# Changing color scheme for some sites

Tags: google-chrome, css, customization

I have often visit sites with bad color scheme.
There is light gray text on white background.

Is any simple way to apply custom (css?) rules for such sites?

I am using google-chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Using stylebot you can locally edit the CSS

Open Stylebot after installation:

[image]

Click on the element you wish to highlight:

[image]

go to advanced:

[image]

Note the div name and the css implemented:

[image]

View the outcome:

[image]

Then simply click the "x" at the top of the screen:

[image]

Comment: After I click on "x" all my style cleared and site became unreadable again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en). Have tried it for several websites, does the job well.

Another option would be [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), but I haven't tried this one.

Comment: Looks like stylebot works bad. After reload all styles cleared. And I doesn't see how to save any settings permanently.

Comment: Can't reproduce that issue. Updated answer to include Stylish.

Comment: May be its about my chrome version -  31.0.1612.0 dev